# Adding fields from Foreign table to export

Tags: django

In the admin list view, the export function allows to export fields from the model (as far as I understood). I wonder, whether it is possible to add fields from related tables to the export option. Say, I have

```
class Author (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False)        
    hometown = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Book (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False)        

    #Some other fields from this model

    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, blank=False, null=False)
```

If I have a Book model like above, it only gives me the author's name in the list view. Therefore it is also available in the export functionality.

If I also want to add `hometown` field from the `Author` model, what would be the way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

the ***unicode*** method should return string

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s, %s" % (self.name, self.hometown)
```

Comment: Is this going to add hometown field to the export list? If so, can you elaborate on how things work?

Comment: Do you need additional column like author's hometown in Admin list view of Book model?

Comment: No. However if I need, I guess I can achieve it by `def hometown(self): return self.author.hometown;` and then in `list_display = [..,'hometown']`.